# UIScrollView horizontal content size adjustment and add UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a question and I try to solve that problem for days now but sadly it doesn't work. 
I am using a UIScrollView for horizontal paging. 
It's actually working but:

Problem 1: whatever I do, the upcoming Images are already shown in the current slide.

on top of this I would also like to have different Labels which belong to the images being showed. Which means that every image has a unique Label from an Array. When paging through, the right Label should be showed under the Image in the UIScrollView.

I attach the code, a Screenshot how it looks like right now and an example how I would like to have it. The left and right buttons of the example doesn't have to be there. If it's easy, feel free to tell me how to do this as well. :)

Thanks already a lot for your help guys!

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    //Mark: Properties



    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!






    var images: [String] = ["Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4"]
    var frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0)

    let titles: [String] = ["Get High", "Get Tipsy", "Get Trippy", "Get fucked"]





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      // Specify how many pages it has = to page control numbers

        pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count
        for index in 0..<images.count {
            frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index) // width x amount of pages
            frame.size = scrollView.frame.size


            // initialize image view "add on top of scroll view"

            let imgView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: images[index])
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imgView)


        }

        // Setting the size of the scroll view

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(images.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

        scrollView.delegate = self

        }


        // Scrollview Method
        // --> Set new image and new page Control position

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        var pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width // what actual page we are on
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }

        }
```

[image: UIScrollView right now]

[image: something like this would be nice :)]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same with collection-view. anyways have you tried Paging Enable ??

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Yes paging is enabled but its still not working... Do you have a suggestion for the collection view? :)

Comment: well what you want to achieve image 1 or 2 ?

Comment: image two with the "hanging guy" that every slide just shows one image...

Comment: ok then you can achieve that by UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource

Comment: Thanks mate! I'm gonna try it and let you know :)

Comment: Sure :) let me know